# How to handle carriage return with windows batch script?

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, cmd

I want to use bat to automate some of my work. It should first look up the value of a certain registry key, and then copy some files to the directory that included in the registry key value. 
I used **reg query** command to look up registry, such as:

```
REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
```

The result seems contains carriage return and I need to remove it, I've tried some solutions but all failed. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that particular case, you can start with:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %i in ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE ^| findstr PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE') do set x=%i
```

which will set `%x%` to x86 (in my case).

If the third value on the line can contain spaces, you'll need to get a bit trickier

---

The following script shows one way to be trickier. It basically uses a debug line to produce fictional output from `reg` that gives you an architecture with spaces.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('echo.    PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE      REG_SZ  x86 64-bit     grunter') do (
    set arch=%%b
)
echo !arch!
endlocal
```

The output of that is:

```
x86 64-bit grunter
```

as expected (keep in mind it collapses multiple spaces into one). The `tokens=2*` bit puts token 2 (`REG_SZ`) into `%%a` and all following tokens into `%%b`.

So a good final script would be:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set id=HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
set key=PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY "!id!" /v !key! ^| findstr !key!') do (
    set arch=%%b
)
echo !arch!
if !arch!==x86 echo arch was x86
endlocal
```

This script outputs:

```
x86
arch was x86
```

so you know it's being set as you desire.

Comment: +1 Thats what I would come up with. If the value contains spaces, you can use `for /f "tokens=2*" ...`. This site gives some explanations: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregistry.php

Comment: @Pax, I've tried your solution. I redirect the result to a txt file:
echo %x% > 1.txt
It still contains a carriage return. It also return false for this statement: if %x%=="x86"

Comment: @eric, echo will add its own line end which is why it's showing up in the file. The reason why your `if` fails is because of the quotes - they should either be around _both_ sides of the `==` or neither side. If you have a look at the updated script at the bottom of my answer, you'll see what I mean - it sets `arch` correctly to `x86`, assuming you architecture _is_ actually x86 of course.